# setCenter() and then move marker vertically higher on the map canvas

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple question, and hopefully there is a simple answer . . . I just can't find it after a couple of hours of searching.

I've got a standard google map with a bunch of markers.  I have a click event on each marker so that when clicked, the map pans the marker to the center and zooms in on it.  No issues there.

Now I want to change the event handler so that when a  marker is clicked the map recenters so that the marker is centered horizontally, but it is vertically towards the top of the map canvas.  Is there a relatively straight forward way of doing this that works across different zoom levels?

Thanks,
Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many ways, e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          this.getMap().setCenter(this.getPosition());
          this.getMap().panBy(0,(this.getMap().getDiv().offsetHeight/2)+this.anchorPoint.y);
        });
```

It puts the marker in the center and then pans the map vertically by `(mapHeight/2-markerHeight)`

Answer (score 1):

You could also muck around with `getProjection()` and the `fromContainerPixelToLatLon` and `fromLatLonToContainerPixel` to set a specific position within the viewable point of the math.

Both of those will give you pixel measurements from the `<div>` element you're using as the map canvas.

c.f. `fromDivPixel` and `ToDivPixel` which will give you the pixel position of the item on the *infinite* div of the map.  Say you've got your map focussed on Africa, right?  And you've got a pin in NYC.  Using the `*DivPixel*` variants will keep your pin in NYC, and then you can pan towards it.  Using `*ContainerPixel*` will move your pin into view on the map regardless of whatever Lat/Lon you've set it to.

Comment: Dr. Molle got there first.  But +1 for showing me something new.